# How to read from a file into an unsigned character buffer and write to a file from it in C

Tags: c, tcp, udp

I would like to read from a file into an unsigned character buffer as well as write that information back into a file. I am using an unsigned character buffer because I need to send this information over a UDP socket.

The problem is I can't seem to find a way to properly read the file from the buffer and write from the buffer.

Can anyone point a way to do this?

Thanks so much

Comment: Could you be more specific?  Perhaps post some sample code and point out what is not working?

Comment: What's wrong with `open`, `read`, and `write`?

Comment: Or even `fopen()`, `fread()`, and `fwrite()`? (Don't forget the `b` modifier in the `fopen` call; has no effect on *nix, but is required on Windows to prevent newline transformations on binary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `write` and `read` functions, or `fread` and `fwrite`. They should do the trick.

For example, you write a buffer to a file with:

```
int fd = open("file", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0600);
write(fd, yourBuffer, numberOfCharactersToWrite);
```

The `write` function may return some error codes, so read it's manual.

`fwrite` is very similar in usage, look at the [site here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fwrite/).